# PLY polygon number

Tags: numbers, polygon, points, ply

I currently work on PLY (Polygon File Format) reader in C++ openGl.

Is the number of points same for every polygon in PLY file?

EXAMPLE: 'N 1 2 3 .. M' is given polygon row in PLY file, it says that the polygon is made of N points.

Is the N same for whole file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the number of points per face in a PLY file may vary from one face to the next. For example, the face list may contain a mix of both triangles and quadrilateral polygons, like this:

```
3 0 1 2
3 0 3 1
4 4 0 2 5
4 6 4 5 7
```

You can see an example of a full PLY file containing faces with different numbers of vertices at [Paul Bourke's PLY File Format page](http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/ply/).

Comment: Thank you! I have already finished my PLY reader/viewer. But it may help others. :-)